# "He gave her a gesture while leaving the room." - Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

The intended use of the sentence is for a scenario where a guy gives a positive indication (with facial expressions) to  an employee before leaving the presentation room.

Is "give a gesture" grammatically correct? Does the sentence portray a positive action?

Comment: It's correct grammar, but used that way, it sounds like it was a rude gesture. Maybe mentino the specific gesture "He gave her a thumbs up...' or 'He flipped her the bird...' or 'A wink and a nod as he left the room left her feeling a little queasy'

Comment: Please can you pin point what you find ungrammatical about the sentence? Searching for errors is off topic, as explained in the [faq]

Comment: @MattЭллен - I was not sure about "gave a gesture" phrase. So, I was asking for suggestions for better word choice.

Comment: As Mitch says, the sentence as written is grammatically correct but, unless the larger context makes it clear, it is is ambiguous. Was it a rude gesture or a positive gesture? Also, it's more common to say "made a gesture" than "gave a gesture".

Comment: Probably if it is a facial expression, I would not use the term "gesture".

Comment: @GEdgar: Very well said; I wouldn't either. I'd be more inclined to say "He flashed her a smile" than "He gave her a gesture."

Comment: A gesture is something you do with your hands or arms; it looks like you are trying to use it for facial expressions—that's not [what gesture means](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gesture).

Answer (score 11):

The sentence in question

> *He gave her a gesture while leaving the room.*

is certainly grammatical.

The phrase *give a gesture* is not idiomatic, however, and not a spectacularly helpful description, since it doesn't include the communicative intent of the gesture. As other comments have made clear, people use gestures for all kinds of purposes, and if this is sposta be a description, it's not doing the job.

This is very much like saying

> *He said a sentence to her while leaving the room.*

The reader's reaction to this sentence is likely to be something like

> *"OK, and ...?"*

because it's the **meaning** of the sentence, or the gesture, that's likely to be important to the reader, not the physical description of the event.

Comment: Agreed.   One often sees 'give' in regards to *specific* gestures:   "He gave her a nod" or "She gave a salute" but to just give "a gesture" sounds incomplete and downright strange.

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic form is *made a gesture to her* (or more rarely, *made her a gesture*) and not *gave her a gesture*. You could use *gave her a signal* or *gave her a sign*.

To me, *gave her a gesture* sounds like a euphemism for *gave her the finger*. If you want to convey a positive meaning, you should use *made.*

Comment: 'made a gesture' is better but still sounds like...well, how many positive gestures are there?

Comment: At least two ... there's the thumbs up, and the circle with the thumb and index finger. And there aren't that many more negative gestures, but you're right--*made a gesture* could easily be negative. You could say *made her a gesture of approval* if you don't want to be more specific.

Comment: At least in my understanding of what OP is trying to say - that the "gesture" conveys some sort of information or communication - *gave her a signal* is the best choice.

Comment: OK. but to me still feels negative when unspecified. Whatever the gesture is, one would say "gave her two thumbs up" or "ok'd her" rather than the generic gesture; like someone else mentioned, its as informative as  "He spoke to her as he left the room."...OK well, what was it that he said?

Answer (score 4):

I would say *He gestured to her as he left the room* if you don't want to specify exactly what it was that he did; remember that a thumbs-up and a middle finger are both gestures, and (in American usage, anyway) have almost exactly opposite meanings - so you are leaving things quite open to the reader's interpretation.

If you want to unambiguously state that he was giving a positive signal to her - and that it was by means of a facial expression - I think I would go with:

> He [winked](http://www.wordnik.com/words/wink) at her as he left the room.

Answer (score 0):

As said its a vague word that implies little other than some sort of non-verbal commincation was passed - you could add an adverb before it, or description after it, or replace it entirely with a more descriptive term.

> He gave her a non-commital gesture

or

> He gave her a rude gestrue...

or

> he gave her a gesture to follow him...

or

> He blew her a kiss...

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically sound, but sentences need to have a sound meaning too.

Exactly who was leaving the room?

Gesture is very vague too, was it a rude gesture, a flirtatious signal, or a polite acknowledgement.  Without clarification, you might have meant anything.

If you wanted ambiguity, use words not typically associated with a particular coloring phrase.  "A rude gesture" has been used as a euphemism so many times that gesture on it's own now colors the language toward rudeness.

```
He motioned to her as (he / she) left the room.
```

Makes just as much sense, (provided you pick one he or she) but doesn't use an awkward word that colors the sentence with possible rudeness.